# What are the effects of introducing raccoons into Germany?

Tags: animal-behaviour, germany, raccoons

I was reading this [answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/11049/8794) about how raccoons were introduced into Germany, and after the other questions on this site about the harm caused by non-native species,(grey squirrels, [house sparrows](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19692/when-and-why-were-house-sparrows-originally-brought-to-the-united-states), etc), it made me wonder what it the effects of raccoons were especially since there is some  [debate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raccoon#Distribution_in_Germany) on the subject.

How do raccoons affect the environment in Germany?

Comment: http://www.businessinsider.com/germany-europe-raccoon-problem-2016-6 may have some data.